# How to concenate string from JArray

Tags: c#

I have a JArray as below:

```
 _ja[0]="AB";
 _ja[1]="CD";
 _ja[2]="EF";
```

How to string concat the above array into a string value delimeted with comma, I expect to get the following:   AB, CD, EF

please help

thanks a lot
Don

Comment: Any attempts.. kindly post your attempt and what issue you faced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.Join`.

Example:

```
_ja[0]="AB";
_ja[1]="CD";
_ja[2]="EF";

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", _ja));
>>> AB, CD, EF
```